# How can I push to a newly-created repo on bitbucket without facing a password challenge?

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket, ssh-keys

I've created a repo on bitbucket.
In a local project I've added my repo as a remote.

When trying to push, I'm prompted for a password.

Bitbucket has a system for passwordless pushing, using a keypair for authentication.
However, this simply isn't working for me at the moment: the keypair system works for any old projects that I've got connected to bitbucket remotes, but not for newly created ones.

How can I fix this and push my code?

Comment: As I understand it, Bitbucket accepts ssh authentication with an ssh public key, so you could use ssh protocol, create a keypair, store the public key on bitbucket, and use that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git%2bssh?tab=Votes

Comment: This works for projects that I've created previously. But doesn't work for new projects.